# Compute cos(x) to 0 when x is 90 degree or pi/2 radian in C++

Tags: c++, trigonometry

```
# include <iostream>
# include <math.h>
# include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

double cosin_value( double value);
double sin_value( double value);
double big_degree (double value);
double big_radian (double value);
double x;
double value;
double degree;
double radian;
const double PI = 3.14159;

char choice;
char yes ;

int main()
 {
cout << "Please enter an angle value => ";
cin >> value;

cout << "Is the angle in Degree or Radian?" << endl;
        cout << "\t" << "Type D if it is in Degree" << endl;
        cout << "\t" << "Type R if it is in Radian" << endl;
        cout << "Your response => ";
        cin >> choice; //degree or radian?

        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(10);

    if (choice == 'D' || choice == 'd')
    {
        big_degree (value);
        cout << " " << "sin(x)   = " << "\t" << sin_value(degree) << endl;
        cout << " " << "cos(x)   = " << "\t" << cosin_value(degree) << endl;
        cout << " " << "tan(x)   = " << "\t" <<  sin_value(degree)/cosin_value(degree) << endl;
    }
    else if (choice == 'R' || choice == 'r')
    {   
        cout << " " << "sin(x)   = " << "\t" << sin_value(radian) << endl;
        cout << " " << "cos(x)   = " << "\t" << cosin_value(radian) <<  endl;
        cout << " " << "tan(x)   = " << "\t" <<   sin_value(radian)/cosin_value(radian) << endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}

// Sine,cosine functions
// angle -360<value<360

double sin_value( double value)
{
int count=1;

double sine, num, dem, sign, term;
sine=0;
sign = 1;   
num = value;
dem = count;

while ( count <= 20 )
{
    term = (num/dem);
    sine = sine + term*sign;
    num = num*value*value;
    count = count + 2;
    dem = dem * count * (count-1);
    sign = -sign;

}
return (sine);  
}   

double cosin_value( double value)
{
int count=0;
double cosine, num, dem, sign, term;
cosine=0;
sign = 1;

num = 1;
dem = 1;

while ( count <= 20 )
{
    term = (num/dem);
    cosine = cosine + term*sign;
    num = num*value*value;
    count = count + 2;
    dem = dem * count * (count-1);
    sign = -sign;
}
return (cosine);
}   

double big_degree (double value)
{
int result;
const int angle=360;
if (value >= 360 || value <= -360)
{
    result=value/angle;
    degree=(value-(result* angle))*PI/180;
}    
else
{
    degree = (value*PI)/180;
}   
return (degree);
 }  

double big_radian (double value)
{
int result;

if (value >= 2*PI || value <= -2*PI)
{
    result=value/(2*PI);
    radian=(value-(result* 2*PI));
}    
else
{
    radian = value;
}   
return (radian);
}
```

Hi, this is basically the whole program I wrote for calculating trigonometric value using the extent knowledge I knew in C++ as a beginner. For a better view, you can refer to this link regarding my code above :[codepad.org](http://codepad.org/dChy8x2E)
the line starting from line 114 onwards are the function that I created. There's a problem there where how can I compute my **cosx** to be 0 when the value is 90 degree or pi/2 radian?
since the program will still calculate **tanx** for me even the value is 90 degree.
Let's say by giving value **90 degree** to the program, it will give me the value of **0.0000013268** instead of **0.000000**
sorry, since I'm just a beginner, the code will look weird for you guys.
I appreciate your guides!
**double big_degree(double value)** means when the **value is >= 360 or <= -360***

Comment: Why do you expect us to wade through over 100 lines of code when you are not prepared to narrow down the problem a little?

Comment: You should include math.h and use **#define M_PI  3.14159265358979323846** from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not allocate any heap space in my brain for digits of pi, but I do remember that [`atan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan)`(1) == pi / 4`.

Change your `PI` constant like so:

```
const double PI = atan(1) * 4;
```

Taking your code, making that change, I get

```
Please enter an angle value => 90
Is the angle in Degree or Radian?
    Type D if it is in Degree
    Type R if it is in Radian
Your response => d
 sin(x)   =     1.0000000000
 cos(x)   =     0.0000000000
 tan(x)   =     15555226593901466.0000000000
```

Comment: may I know that what does it meant by atan(1) * 4?

Comment: `atan` is for "arctangent" from trigonometry. See this link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan

Comment: @Prashtan Thanks for the guides! It worked, but I will need time to understand that code. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for out of box solution :) but isn't tan(90) undefined? infinity?

Comment: @someone_smiley ya, that's why, I'm having trouble with this problem now... any guides?

Comment: @Asus93 : I think the value of tan with angle approach 90 degree is too big to store in any data type. so it is not possible to evaluate tan 90. I just wonder y Prashant get real value after evaluating it. there atleast should be flag or exception indicate unsuccessful evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your code. The input you have given is not sufficiently accurate. Calculate the proper value of pi/2, and you will get a sufficiently accurate value.
Also, if you want to round off the values you can use
#rounded off value=Math.Round(#old value, 4)

Comment: sorry, I'm not clear with the usage of it, can you briefly describe it? Thanks!

Comment: The value you want to roud off is given as paramete(old value), the value want it to be returned is rounded off value. The 2nd parameter is the precision to which you want to approximate.Ex, for your code it is cosine=Math.Round(cosine,4); add it before the return statement and afterthe while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
const double PI = 3.14159;
```

The more precise you make this definition, the more close to `0` will the value of `cos PI/2` get!

If you get the input itself in radians, there also the same criteria applies.

Comment: 'const double PI = 3.14159;' hi, but I already put my pi to the value as stated there....

Comment: that means I have to make my Pi=3.141592654?

Answer (score 0):

My soulution:

```cpp
double mySin(double x)
{
    if (fmod(x, std::numbers::pi) == 0)
        return 0;
    return sin(fmod(x, std::numbers::pi * 2.0));
}

double myCos(double x) { return mySin(x + std::numbers::pi / 2); }

myCos(std::numbers::pi / 2) == 0 //True
myCos(std::numbers::pi) == -1 //True
myCos(std::numbers::pi * 2) == 1 //True
```